# add to bundle without extract it

Tags: android, bundle

I have two classes. **class A** and class **B**. In class A, I put some strings into a bundle object and then send it to **class B**.

My question is here:
Can I put some `string` or `int` to this bundle directly without extracting it in class B and add extra info to it and then create a new Bundle.

*******EDIT*******
other scenario:

I have sent a bundle from intent service to activity then in activity I want to put some extra to this bundle and finally I'll send this bundle to background thread for saving on sharePreference. how could i do that?

Comment: sayres kabir as you're a very good programmer, how about to try that out, and see if class C can read the value added in class B?

Comment: @Alessio , actually second scenario is my main question.

Comment: any good reason why you want to save it to SP from background thread? Access and store to SP is quick enough that you can do it from UI thread without no problems at all. Just make sure you persist quick data like a string and an int, and you don't instead parse on the fly json to string before you persist it (even in that case is still duable, and you good programmer can easily measure it)

Comment: @Alessio . because on my activity I have a dialog and user must enter additional info.then I want mix this new info whit older bundle and send to background thread for saving

Comment: you still don't explain me why you want that to happen in the background thread. You can do it from the dialog directly, no need to move the logic to background thread. If you really want to do so, yes you still can. Bundle is an object, so you can pass it around and manipulate it without any problem. I still think the title and your questions are misleading, so give it a try and see how you can do it.

Comment: on my login activity , when user enter user name and pass , this info is sent to intent service. inside intent service i connect to webservice and got related information about user. after that i put all the information on bundle and finally by ResultReceiver i send to the login activity. on login activity, a dialog is opened and user according some info that received from server must enter an extra information to this bundle and so on.

Comment: @Alessio why i have to save info into the SP on dialog? dialog is executed on UIthread. and it make a problem for my app

Comment: why would that be a problem? It takes 2ms to save a value to SP

Comment: look at the [first code example](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) written by Google's engineers, they store to SP from an Activity. No problems with it.

Comment: @Alessio . if you see Android Developers channel on youtube , MR Cole McCandles explained for do not using of saving Sp on mainThread. your link is just an example .

Comment: Link? Then do it in bg thread if you prefer, but if you measure it you'll see is immediate

Comment: @Alessio https://www.youtube.com/user/androiddevelopers

Comment: Link to the video you refer, not to the channel please. Possibly also minutes and seconds you refer to

Comment: @Alessio , dude i do not remember that which one that video was.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qk5F6Bxqhr4&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that. So in your Class B, when you want to open Class C, you can get the bundle from previous intent and then go ahead and add to the same bundle and open C

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityC.class);
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
    bundle.putString("newKey","newValue");
    newIntent.putExtras(bundle);
}
startActivity(newIntent);
```

**Update**

since you want to pass this Bundle in BG thread and assuming you are using AsyncTask for that you can do following -

Declare your Async task as below -

```
 class MyBGClass extends AsyncTask<Bundle,Void,Void>{
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }



        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Bundle... params) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Then to call it you can do -

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
    bundle.putString("newKey","newValue");
}
new MyBGClass().execute(bundle);
```

**UPDATE 2:**
To pass data from your resultReceiver -

```
receiver.send(RESULT_CODE, bundle);
```

Then in your activity where you would have passed this resultreceiver to your Service implement

```
 @Override
protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {

    //resultData is your bundle. to add to it -
    if (resultData != null) {
        resultData.putString("newKey","newValue");
    }
}
```

Then call your BG thread.

Change the constructer of your WorkerThread class like below and pass bundle to your thread when you create the object of the class-

```
private class WorkerThread extends HandlerThread {
    private static final int SAVE = 1;
    PreferenceModel instancePreferenceModel;
    Bundle bundle;
    private Handler mHandler;
    public WorkerThread(Bundle bundle) {
        super("WorkerThread", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        App app = (App) getApplication();
        this.bundle = bundle;
        instancePreferenceModel = app.getInstancePreferenceModel();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLooperPrepared() {
        super.onLooperPrepared();

        mHandler = new Handler(getLooper()) {

            @Override // receive message from uiThread as Bundle object.
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                switch (msg.what) {

                    case SAVE:
                        Log.i(TAG, "handleMessage: saved completed");
                        Bundle data = (Bundle) msg.obj;
                        Log.i(TAG, "getData: " + data.getString(LoginIntentService.EXTRA_FIRST_NAME));
                        instancePreferenceModel.saveUserInfo(data);
                        break;
                }

            }

        };

    }

    // this method is access to main ui thread.by this method UiThread can send a Message
    // Background Thread
    public void write(Bundle b) {
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.obj = b;
        Message obtain = Message.obtain(mHandler, SAVE, msg.obj);
        mHandler.sendMessage(obtain);
    }

}
```

Comment: actually I have sent bundle from Intent service to my activity by resultReceiver. I want but some extra to this bundle and then sent it to another class for saving to sharePreference. now how could i do that?

Comment: You can do it same way. So use the above code in your activity from which you want to send to another class(I suppose another activity or fragment right?)

Comment: No, I send this bundle from intent service to activity then in activity i want to put some extra to this bundle and finally i'll send this bundle to background thread for saving on sharePreference

Comment: Why do you want to save in Shared Pref in BG thread? So for putExtra part you can do it this way itself. Then instead of passing the bundle through an intent to another activity you can directly pass it as a method parameter.

Comment: because on my activity I have a dialog and user must enter additional info.then I want mix this new info whit older bundle and send to background thread for saving

Comment: @sayreskabir Updated my answer

Comment: thank you but I do not want to use of AsyncTask. I am using Thread handler for my strategy purpose..

Comment: Can you add some code on how your thread handler looks. Otherwise all my answers would be a bit vague

Comment: Update my answer again :)

Comment: before that i send to thread I have to change older bundle .not inside thread.

Comment: exactly. after changing , I,ll send new bundle to thread and so on

Comment: So is anything left. I guess i answered your query right?

Comment: on above post yes."yes changing has to be done before calling the thread ".yes

Comment: So i am now confused. Adding to old bundle part i have already told. right? It was the part of my Update 1 as well. There instead of calling Async you call your thread. That remains same. Do you want  me to tell you how to pass bundle from intent service to activity?

Comment: I said before. I am using of ResultReceiver for sending bundle from intentservice to activity.

Comment: So then all parts of your questions are answered. You already know how to pass to activity. I told how to get bundle in activity and add new values to it and then how to pass it to thread. So now no part is left so I think you can accept the answer

Comment: dude , I before know all of your answer.no one of your answer is useful  for me(but thank you). look: I send bundle from intentservice to activity by resultReceiver.in activity i want to add one variable to this bundle that arrived from intent service.now how could i do that??

Comment: Man your question is very confusing in that case if you knew all the answer. If you want to add another to existing bundle Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
    bundle.putString("newKey","newValue");
}

Comment: dude you mistake is here: `Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras()`. resultReceiver did not send a bundle by Intent.for this i can't use  `getIntent()`. resultReceiver send like this: `receiver.send(RESULT_RECEIVER_USER_ALL_INFO, bundle);`

Comment: You said you already know how to send data. So basically you would already be passing your resultReceiver to your service when you start your service right? now to send a bundle from that receiver to activity you have to use the send method Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(Constants.RESULT_DATA_KEY, message);
    mReceiver.send(resultCode, bundle);
Then get this value in your activity in @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData)

Comment: Added another update on  how to get bundle from resultreceiver

Comment: :-( I do not know how can i explain :-(. I know how can I use of resultReceiver. my question is when i receive bundle inside activity, how can i put something into this bundle??

Comment: Yes that i showed. You need to do that in onReceiveResult method

Comment: Glad I could help after so much confusion. Thanks for accepting @sayreskabir